# How do I put text from a text file into a list and sort it?

Tags: python

A quiz that should input score and name into a text file, then have the option to **output the scores from the text file** (**biggest to smallest**). I need a section of code that will output the text from the file into a list and then allow me to **sort the list** accordingly.

```
import os
import random

x = 0

while x <1:


    teacher = input("What is your class, choose from 'A', 'B' or 'C'? ").upper() 

    if teacher == 'A':
        if os.path.exists("classA.txt") == False: 
            myfile = open("classA.txt","w")
            myfile.close()
        x = x + 1 

    elif teacher == 'B':
        if os.path.exists("classB.txt") == False:
            myfile = open("classB.txt","w")
            myfile.close()
        x = x + 1

    elif teacher == 'C':
        if os.path.exists("classC.txt") == False:
            myfile = open("classC.txt","w")
            myfile.close()
        x = x + 1

    else:
        teacher != 'A' , 'B' , 'C' 
        print("Incorrect input, choose from 'A', 'B' or 'C' ")


score = 0
name = input("Please enter your name ")

for i in range (1,11):

    no1 = random.randint(0,11)
    no2 = random.randint(0,11)    
    question = random.randint(1,3)


    if question == 1:
        answer = no1 + no2
        guess = int(input("Question "+ str(i) + ") What is " + str(no1) + "+" + str(no2) + "= "))
        if guess == answer:
            score +=1
            print("That's the correct answer")
        else:
            print ("That's the incorrect answer")

    elif question == 2:
        answer = no1 * no2
        guess = int(input("Question "+ str(i) + ") What is " + str(no1) + "*" + str(no2) + "= "))
        if guess == answer:
            score +=1
            print("That's the correct answer")          
        else:
            print ("That's the incorrect answer")


    elif question == 3:
        answer = no1 - no2
        guess = int(input("Question "+ str(i) + ") What is " + str(no1) + "-" + str(no2) + "= "))
        if guess == answer:
            score +=1
            print("That's the correct answer")

        else:
            print ("That's the incorrect answer")

print ("Your score is " + str(score))



if teacher == 'A':
    classA = []
    classA.append([name , str(score)])
    classA = open("classA.txt","a")
    classA.write(name + str(score)+"\n")
    classA.close()


elif teacher == 'B':
    classB = []
    classB.append([name , str(score)])
    classB = open("classB.txt","a")
    classB.write(name + str(score)+"\n")
    classB.close()


elif teacher == 'C':
    classC = []
    classC.append([name ,  str(score)])
    classC = open("classC.txt","a")
    classC.write(name + str(score)+"\n")
    classC.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only built in functions:

Assuming your text file looks like this:

```
John 13
Jill 12
Juan 14
Phil 15
bill 16
```

You would do something to this effect:

```
filen = open('filename.txt', 'r+')
filetxt = filen.read()
#filelist = []; filelist = filetxt.split(' ') #Splits by spaces
filelist = []; filelist = filetxt.split('\n')
#filelist = []; filelist = filetxt.split('') #Put whatever it should split by in the ('')
gradelist = []
for i in filelist:
    if i[-3:][:1] == '1': s = i[-3:]
    else: s = i[-2:]
    gradelist.append(s)
    gradelist.sort()
    b=0
    for x in gradelist:
        if x in i:
            gradelist[b] = i
        b=b+1
a=gradelist[0]
gradelist.remove(a)
gradelist.insert(len(gradelist), a)
```

`print gradelist` Returns `['Jill 12', 'John 13', 'Juan 14', 'Phil 15', 'bill 16']`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest while you enter the scores into the file use a delimiter to separate the score and name. Eg: classA.write(name +"-"+ str(score)+"\n")

This piece of code will do the Required :

```
import operator
f=open("classA.txt")
content={}
for line in f:
    content[line.strip().split("-")[0]]= line.strip().split("-")[1]
sorted_x = reversed(sorted(content.items(),     key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
for aTuple in sorted_x:
    print(aTuple[0] +" : "+aTuple[1])
```

Comment: It's a list of tuples  of the form ("name",score). Did this for future references.

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehensions to read the contents into a list of lists.. Then use `itemgetter` to `sort`.

```
from operator import itemgetter

lines = [line.strip().split(' ') for line in open('results.txt')]

for each in lines:
    each[1] = int(each[1])
lines.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
print lines
```

Answer (score -1):

To take in the text from a file into a list you need("r+" is so you can use readlines)

```
examplefile=open("filename.txt","r+")
```

you can then use "readlines()" to save the contents of the file to a list

```
listofcontents=examplefile.readlines()
```

the contents of the file are now in the list "listofcontents" separated by each line in the original text file allowing you to sort it.